# Can't connect to MySQL server error 113

Tags: php, mysqli, runtime-error

Trying to make a simple connect to my servers MySQL database and I get

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<host>' (113)`

netstat -tulpen has a :3306 record

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999        801279      32067/mysqld
```

My bind-address in my.cnf is set to `0.0.0.0` and I still can't manage to connect to a database.

My MySQL users

```
+------------------+------------------------+
| User             | Host                   |
+------------------+------------------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1              |
| root             | localhost              |
| root             | <ip>                   |
+------------------+------------------------+
```

I can connect from the inside of my server.

What i'm missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That (113) is "No route to host".  Do you have an IP address configured on both machines, and is it routable?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about servers machine, as I get it just an hour ago. Where I can check? I'm not familiar with that kind of stuff. Server runs on Ubuntu. Also, I can connect to a server machine via ssh, doesn't that mean that the IP address is configured?

Answer (score 11):

the 113 error shows "no route to host" error.you must configure your ip address on both machines.
of course,it must be routable.else, it wont work.

Comment: I'm actually not sure about servers machine, as I get it just an hour ago. Where I can check? I'm not familiar with that kind of stuff. Server runs on Ubuntu. Also, I can connect to a server machine via ssh, doesn't that mean that the IP address is configured?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: This answer is not helpful. Please add more details.

Comment: @Gerfried what he means is that this is a NETWORK ISSUE. For example, I came here with the same error message, but I understand what marc_s is saying. So I tried to ping the database server, and I get "Destination host unreachable". So both myself and the OP need to investigate and fix the network connectivity to the database server.

Comment: I currently have an error 113 from Nagios.  Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.2.20.208' (113) However, I can utilize the same user and password (from the Nagios host, and from the local mysql host) to connect to the mysql service, via IP address.  Oh, and they're on the same subnet, so no routers are required, and both servers have their firewalls disabled, so there are other possible problems outside of "the network" which can cause an error 113 to occur.

Comment: my problem solved by opening port of 3306 using firewall-cmd on linux (centos 7)

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, there are two options.  The most likely is that your firewall is blocking that port still, so external cannot access.  The alternative, and weirder one, is an identity issue.  MySQL does not allow, by default, the admin user to login both internally AND externally.  You will need to define a Host and User pair for this identity to be allowed somewhere other than "localhost" to login from.

First, login to mysql server, and then the mysql service.

```
    root# mysql -u root -p
```

Next, open the database named "mysql" and look at your user of interest.  My example will be my "root" user.

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> select * from user where User="root";
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Host      | User | Password                                  | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| localhost | root | *A86DD7ED2F8269DFFDC595311DF5FF08872C12AB | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
| kickseed  | root | *A86DD7ED2F8269DFFDC595311DF5FF08872C12AB | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
| 127.0.0.1 | root | *A86DD7ED2F8269DFFDC595311DF5FF08872C12AB | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
| 10.%.%.%  | root | *A86DD7ED2F8269DFFDC595311DF5FF08872C12AB | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
```

As you can see, I have four separate entries for root: One for local, one for the loopback, one for server kickseed, and one for the development network. You will need to go through the create and grant steps as if it were a new user, and set your permissions accordingly.